# Magento2 - Redirect the customer dashboard after reset password success

Tags: magento2, password

I am new to Magento. Please look at my steps. **I need to redirect the customer to the dashboard, after a successful password reset**.

1. Click on the reset password link, and add customer email address.
2. Customer will receive the password reset link.
3. Once clicking the link, it will redirect to the password reset form.
4. Once change the password,

> "CUSTOMER SHOULD BE ABLE TO REDIRECT TO CUSTOMER DASHBOARD ITSELF.
>   DON`T NEED TO LOGIN AGAIN."

Thanks

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea --

You need to override controller using `<preference>` in your module.

> `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/AccountResetPasswordPost.php`

in this file you need to put below code in `execute` function-

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resetPasswordToken = (string)$this->getRequest()->getQuery('token');
        $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
        $password = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        $passwordConfirmation = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('password_confirmation');

        if ($password !== $passwordConfirmation) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("New Password and Confirm New Password values didn't match."));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/createPassword', ['id' => $customerId, 'token' => $resetPasswordToken]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        if (iconv_strlen($password) <= 0) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please enter a new password.'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/createPassword', ['id' => $customerId, 'token' => $resetPasswordToken]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        try {
            $customerEmail = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId)->getEmail();
            $this->credentialsValidator->checkPasswordDifferentFromEmail($customerEmail, $password);
            $this->accountManagement->resetPassword($customerEmail, $resetPasswordToken, $password);
            $this->session->unsRpToken();
            $this->session->unsRpCustomerId();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You updated your password.'));

            /* start code to customer login and redirect to dashboard */
            // use dependency injection instead of object manager
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

            $this->session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('url_to_customer_dashboard');
            return $resultRedirect;

            /* end code*/

            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/login');
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($error->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving the new password.'.$exception->getMessage()));
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/createPassword', ['id' => $customerId, 'token' => $resetPasswordToken]);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

**Extra Notes:**-

(a) use dependency injection instead of object manager.

(b) use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654718/how-to-override-controller-in-magento2) to know how to use preference.

I hope it would help.

Comment: @Wad, please mark it as answer it helped you. thanks